# jQuery height() width()

Tags: jquery, image, height, width

I have an image on the page:

```
<img id="foobar" src="emptySpace.gif" />
```

The image has an `absolute` position of `left: 0` and `top: 0` in a .css file.

When I try this in JavaScript `onmouseover`, the height and width don't change. What am I missing?

```
var image = jQuery("#foobar");
image.height(500).width(500);
```

What gives?

Comment: that works on an image tag, but have you tried it with a real GIF? maybe you just don't see the results? or post your onmouseover code. works in firebug just fine

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that code is being run - that the function is indeed being called on mouseover?

You could also try using the css() method:

```
image.css({height:'500px',width:'500px'});
```